# DataCloneError in firefox when posting to web worker

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-worker

I am working on a helper library called Ozai to make web workers easier, but am running in to a problem in firefox. I create a web worker from a URL Blob and attempt to post this payload to it:

```
msg = {
    "id":"0fae0ff8-bfd1-49ea-8139-3d03fb9584e4",
    "fn":"fn",
    "args":[100,200]
}
```

Using this code:

```
worker.postMessage(msg)
```

But it **throws a `DataCloneError` exception**. It looks like Firefox's implementation of structured cloning is failing on a very simple object. The code runs without problems on Chrome and Safari, but fails in the latest version of Firefox. Am I missing something here?  How do I get around this (preferably without stringifying the payload)?

**Here's a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/V8aCy/6/

And a pic of Firelord Ozai:

[image]

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42376465/1034782 Simple.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to call `postMessage` with an object that has a property referencing `arguments`. That doesn't work because [data has to be transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage), which means either fully JSON-serializable or implementing `Transferable` (e.g. ArrayBuffer), which `arguments` is not.

Use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)` to convert `arguments` into an array, which can be serialized (cloned) if the contents are OK.

[Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8aCy/7/).