# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I'm trying to call

```
parent.postMessage(obj, 'whatever');
```

from within an iframe and I'm getting this error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned.`

Comment: This happens all the time, if something can not be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm. This algorithm is used by `window.postMessage`. For more information see my **[answer with solution and detailed explanation why it happans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223341)**.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

It turns out the object I passed had methods, which is why the error message said `An object could not be cloned`.

In order to fix this, you can do the following:

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
parent.postMessage(obj, 'whatever');
```

Comment: That's good to know, because Mozilla says messages are serialized for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage Makes sense it wouldn't know how to serialize a function...

Comment: were you able to access methods on that object after passing to parent??

Comment: Note that doing so you'll crash on cyclics (which should be preserved by postMessage) instead of on functions.

Comment: In my case the problem were caused by an nonexistent variable passed in parameters.

Comment: When using AngularJS, I found this solution removed fields that were of TrustedValueHolderType.  I'm looking for a solution for dealing with this.

Comment: My semi-cheap catch all hack around this is to stringify the payload and convert again on recieving, strips out the unparsable junk.

Comment: Also we can't pass DOM object as, "The ownership of these objects is given to the destination side and they are no longer usable on the sending side".

Comment: Don't forget issue about stringifying and parsing Error objects, it results in an empty obect.  You probably wanna do it in a catch clause for the initial method

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you're trying to pass, a more surgical approach could be to use simpler data structures that are compatible with `postMessage()`.

The following will throw the error since `postMessage` can't serialize `SetIterator`:

```
let s = new Set();
parent.postMessage({s: s.values()}, '*');
```

The following will work as expected since `postMessage` can serialize `Array`:

```
let s = new Set();
parent.postMessage({s: [...s]}, '*');
```

This approach works more in line with the intent of implicit serialization by `postMessage()`. When you need more complex data structures or can't be bothered to get all surgical, the good ole `JSON.stringify/parse` hammer works just fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have functions in the object (or in nested objects) that you post, then cloning will fail.

I had this problem in the context of messaging an object to a web worker. The solution was to in-place convert all functions to source code strings, post the modified object and a list of paths (each an array of keys) to the found functions, and then convert the strings back to functions. The approach of storing paths to functions separately is safe in the sense that no previously unexisting functions can be created.

Here is my implementation. Nested arrays and objects are handled. `null` values are handled. Circular references are not handled and will result in `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

```js
function deepFunctionsToStrings(obj, functionPaths = [], path = []) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        path.push(key);
        let value = obj[key];
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            deepFunctionsToStrings(value, functionPaths, path)
        } else if (typeof value === 'function') {
            obj[key] = value.toString();
            functionPaths.push([...path]);
        }
        path.pop();
    }
    return functionPaths;
}

function deepStringsToFunctions(obj, functionPaths) {
    for (let functionPath of functionPaths) {
        let finalKey = functionPath.pop();
        let value = obj;
        for (let key of functionPath) {
            value = value[key];
        }
        value[finalKey] = eval(value[finalKey]);
    }
}
```

To post the object:

```js
let objFunctionPaths = deepFunctionsToStrings(obj);
worker.postMessage({
    obj: obj,
    objFunctionPaths: objFunctionPaths
});
deepStringsToFunctions(obj, objFunctionPaths);
```

To receive the object in the web worker:

```js
onmessage = function (e) {
    obj = e.data.obj;
    deepStringsToFunctions(obj, e.data.objFunctionPaths);
}
```