# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window' GoogleTagManager

Tags: javascript, error-handling, google-tag-manager

Recently, I get this **postMessage couldn't be cloned** error. It is happening on most of the latest browsers like Chrome 68, Firefox 61.0, IE11, Edge.

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': `function (a){if(qe.$a.hasOwnProperty(a))return qe.$a[a]}` could not be cloned.

The stack trace is:

> Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': `function (a){if(qe.$a.hasOwnProperty(a))return qe.$a[a]}` could not be cloned.
>   at _reportEvent (eval at  (:1:35637), :94:35)
>   at eval (eval at  (:1:35637), :55:5)
>   at eval (eval at  (:1:35637), :433:11)

Searching through the source of my page in DevTools shows `gtm.js` as the source of the code fragment:

[image: gtm.js shown as source of the function]

I have a Google Tag Manager tracking code on my page.  Why is this happening?

Comment: I just started seeing this error in our app as well, starting a few days ago, even though we made no code changes. It happens in all major browsers (chrome 68, Firefox, Edge 17), but only on Windows.

Comment: I have also started seeing this error recently - in Linux+Chrome, iOS+Safari, Windows+Chrome.  We only recently added Google Tag Manager to our app.  Next line of the stack trace is `at _reportEvent`

Comment: First occurrence we say was 2018-08-30T17:13 UTC. Seems to be on all browsers/devices and we also traced it to GTM.

Comment: The following might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376464/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-window-an-object-co

Comment: @DanieSchoeman seen that, but since this error is not in GTM code we can't really fix it that way. I think?

Comment: correction : ... since this error is in GTM code ...

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue with my own GTM installation at all, so I think it may be related to specific tags that those who are getting this error have in place. I think it'd really help if we could see some links to your production sites, or GTM containers to further diagnose where exactly this issue stems from.

Comment: In case it helps figure out the cause: the only active tracking code in my GTM is for Facebook Pixel.  There is also a Pardot tracking code, however it is not active on the hostname the errors occur in.  I have also edited the question to add a stack trace, which shows the error is an anonymous code block.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a screenshot showing `gtm.js` as the source of the function.

Comment: @MichaelM does your `gtm.js` include the relevant function (see screenshot in the edited question)?  I don't get this error in every client (I cannot reproduce it).  So the environment is probably relevant.

Comment: Found another list of things to check that might cause problems:
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-preview-mode-not-working/  and https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-404-error-gtm-js/

Comment: It might very well be that a [ (a)) or [a] or $a ] is empty for some or other reason: (a){if(qe.$a.hasOwnProperty(a))return qe.$a[a]}

Comment: I'm seeing this in the Microsoft Power BI Javascript libraries.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This happens all the time, if something can not be duplicated by the **[structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)**. This algorithm is used by **[`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)**. If we read the documentation from **[`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)** for the first parameter:

> **message**
> *Data to be sent to the other window. The data is serialized using the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm).*

and then open the description from *structured clone algorithm* (see last link above) then we can read:

> *The structured clone algorithm* is an algorithm defined by the HTML5 specification for copying complex JavaScript objects. It is used internally when transferring data to and from Workers via `postMessage()` or when storing objects with `IndexedDB`. It builds up a clone by recursing through the input object while maintaining a map of previously visited references in order to avoid infinitely traversing cycles.
>
> **Things that don't work with structured clone**
>
> - `Error` and `Function` objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a
>   `DATA_CLONE_ERR` exception.
> - Attempting to clone `DOM` nodes will likewise throw a `DATA_CLONE_ERR` exception.
> - Certain parameters of objects are not preserved:
>
>   - The `lastIndex` field of `RegExp` objects is not preserved.
>   - Property descriptors, setters, and getters (as well as similar metadata-like features) are not duplicated. For example, if an object
>     is marked read-only using a property descriptor, it will be read-write
>     in the duplicate, since that's the default condition.
>   - The prototype chain does not get walked and duplicated.
>
> **Supported types**
>
> - [All primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values) *(Note: However not symbols)*
> - [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) object
> - [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object
> - [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
> - [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)   *(Note: The lastIndex field is not preserved.)*
> - [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)
> - [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)
> - [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)
> - [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer)
> - [`ArrayBufferView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView) *(Note: This basically means all typed arrays like Int32Array etc.)*
> - [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData)
> - [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
> - [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) *(Note: This just includes plain objects (e.g. from object literals))*
> - [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
> - [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

I tested it with some objects and I can show you following examples when this is happening...

**Error-Example with custom function**

```js
var obj = {something: function(){}};
window.postMessage(obj, '*'); // DataCloneError
```

**Error-Example with native function**

```js
var obj = {something: window.alert};
window.postMessage(obj, '*'); // DataCloneError
```

The same we will see with native functions like `Boolean`, `Date`, `String`, `RegExp`, `Number`, `Array`.

**Error-Example with native object**

```js
var obj = {something: document};
window.postMessage(obj, '*'); // DataCloneError
```

**Error-Example with HTML element object**

```js
var obj = {something: document.createElement('b')};
window.postMessage(obj, '*'); // DataCloneError
```

We could write more examples if we read the description from *The structured clone algorithm* above, but I think here it is enough.

### What we could do to avoid this error

In our code we could use only supported types (see the list above) in our objects. But in not our code we have to contact the developers from this code and write them how they have to correct their code. In the case from the Google Tag Manager you could write it to [the Official Google Tag Manager Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/tag-manager) with description how they have to correct their code.

**Workaround for some browsers**

In some browsers you can not override native methods for security reasons. For example **IE does not allow to override `window.postMessage`**. But other browsers like Chrome allow to override this method like follows:

```
var postMessageTemp = window.postMessage;
window.postMessage = function(message, targetOrigin, transfer)
{
    postMessageTemp(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message)), targetOrigin, transfer)
};
```

But note that `window` is a global object of JavaScript context and it is not created from the `prototype`. In other words: you can not override it with `window.prototype.postMessage = ...`.

**Example with workaround**

```js
var obj = {something: window};

var postMessageTemp = window.postMessage;
window.postMessage = function(message, targetOrigin, transfer)
{
    function cloneObject(obj)
    {
        var clone = {};
        for(var i in obj)
        {
            if(typeof(obj[i]) == 'object' && obj[i] != null)
            {
                if((''+obj[i]) == '[object Window]')
                {
                    delete obj[i];
                    continue;
                }

                clone[i] = cloneObject(obj[i]);
            }
            else
                clone[i] = obj[i];
        }
        return clone;
    }

    // to avoid weird error causing by window object by JSON.stringify() execution.
    var clone = cloneObject(message);

    postMessageTemp(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clone)), targetOrigin, transfer)
};

window.postMessage(obj, '*');

console.log('We do not have any errors.');
```

**How to implement this workaround**

Please put this overriden `window.postMessage` function in script part in your HTML page before Google Tag Manager script. But in better way you could help the developers from Google Tag Manager to understand and to correct this error and you can wait for corrected Google Tag Manager script.

Comment: Looks like someone did post the question on  the GTM forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/TCLRKmONUCs;context-place=forum/tag-manager

Comment: @Yoshi, but it is the same question like from OP and nobody has answered this question. This was copied from our question before a have answered this question. May be someone wanted earn this bounty on this way.

Comment: Hey Bharata, Thanks for your beautiful answer. As you have shown few reasons why it occursand it is acceptable as I have tried those on my end. The major problem that I face is the error doesn't occur in any of the devices that I test it on. As you suggested I can try the overwrite method but again I can only assume that it works. Hope it works.

Comment: @cris the reason you may not see it on your own devices is because it comes from Facebook's crawlers.  See my additional answer.

Comment: @NadeemAhmad, I think, that you have misunderstood something. Maybe you have executed one from 4 first snippets with the code line `window.postMessage(obj, '*'); // DataCloneError`? In this case it should be an arror. I wrote for a reason the comment there. Only in the last snippet is the solution. Do you have misunderstood it?

Comment: @Bharata yes, I tried the workaround snippet. I passed a big chunk of an object and it caused this.

Comment: Another error case is when you trying to post Proxy object, used a lot in reactive frameworks such as Vue. ```
const obj = new Proxy({}, {});
window.postMessage(obj, '*'); // DataCloneError
```
or in Vue
```
const obj = reactive({});
window.postMessage(obj, '*'); // DataCloneError
```

Answer (score 7):

These errors are caused by Facebook crawlers executing JavaScript code.

I have had occurrences of this error from these IPs (all in the Facebook IP ranges) and user agents:

```
66.220.149.14 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
  31.13.115.2 - Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
 173.252.87.1 - Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
69.171.251.11 - facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

To get an up to date list of Facebook crawler IPs, see this command from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/ :

`whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route`

You will need to update your error reporting mechanism to filter out errors from these IP ranges.

You could do this on the client side in JavaScript by determining the user's IP address upon an error (see [How to get client's IP address using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript)).

Or you could do this on the server side.  Here is an example for ASP.NET MVC:

```
using System.Linq;
// Requires the IPAddressRange NuGet library:
// https://www.nuget.org/packages/IPAddressRange/
using NetTools;

public class FacebookClientDetector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The list of CIDR ranges of facebook IPs that its crawlers use.
    /// To generate, run
    ///     whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route
    /// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/
    /// </summary>
    static readonly string[] facebookIpRanges = new string[] {
        "204.15.20.0/22",
        "69.63.176.0/20",
        "66.220.144.0/20",
        "66.220.144.0/21",
        "69.63.184.0/21",
        "69.63.176.0/21",
        "74.119.76.0/22",
        "69.171.255.0/24",
        "173.252.64.0/18",
        "69.171.224.0/19",
        "69.171.224.0/20",
        "103.4.96.0/22",
        "69.63.176.0/24",
        "173.252.64.0/19",
        "173.252.70.0/24",
        "31.13.64.0/18",
        "31.13.24.0/21",
        "66.220.152.0/21",
        "66.220.159.0/24",
        "69.171.239.0/24",
        "69.171.240.0/20",
        "31.13.64.0/19",
        "31.13.64.0/24",
        "31.13.65.0/24",
        "31.13.67.0/24",
        "31.13.68.0/24",
        "31.13.69.0/24",
        "31.13.70.0/24",
        "31.13.71.0/24",
        "31.13.72.0/24",
        "31.13.73.0/24",
        "31.13.74.0/24",
        "31.13.75.0/24",
        "31.13.76.0/24",
        "31.13.77.0/24",
        "31.13.96.0/19",
        "31.13.66.0/24",
        "173.252.96.0/19",
        "69.63.178.0/24",
        "31.13.78.0/24",
        "31.13.79.0/24",
        "31.13.80.0/24",
        "31.13.82.0/24",
        "31.13.83.0/24",
        "31.13.84.0/24",
        "31.13.85.0/24",
        "31.13.86.0/24",
        "31.13.87.0/24",
        "31.13.88.0/24",
        "31.13.89.0/24",
        "31.13.90.0/24",
        "31.13.91.0/24",
        "31.13.92.0/24",
        "31.13.93.0/24",
        "31.13.94.0/24",
        "31.13.95.0/24",
        "69.171.253.0/24",
        "69.63.186.0/24",
        "31.13.81.0/24",
        "179.60.192.0/22",
        "179.60.192.0/24",
        "179.60.193.0/24",
        "179.60.194.0/24",
        "179.60.195.0/24",
        "185.60.216.0/22",
        "45.64.40.0/22",
        "185.60.216.0/24",
        "185.60.217.0/24",
        "185.60.218.0/24",
        "185.60.219.0/24",
        "129.134.0.0/16",
        "157.240.0.0/16",
        "157.240.8.0/24",
        "157.240.0.0/24",
        "157.240.1.0/24",
        "157.240.2.0/24",
        "157.240.3.0/24",
        "157.240.4.0/24",
        "157.240.5.0/24",
        "157.240.6.0/24",
        "157.240.7.0/24",
        "157.240.9.0/24",
        "157.240.10.0/24",
        "157.240.16.0/24",
        "157.240.19.0/24",
        "157.240.11.0/24",
        "157.240.12.0/24",
        "157.240.13.0/24",
        "157.240.14.0/24",
        "157.240.15.0/24",
        "157.240.17.0/24",
        "157.240.18.0/24",
        "157.240.20.0/24",
        "157.240.21.0/24",
        "157.240.22.0/24",
        "157.240.23.0/24",
        "129.134.0.0/17",
        "157.240.0.0/17",
        "69.171.250.0/24",
        "204.15.20.0/22",
        "69.63.176.0/20",
        "69.63.176.0/21",
        "69.63.184.0/21",
        "66.220.144.0/20",
        "69.63.176.0/20",
    };

    public static bool IsFacebookClient(string ip)
    {
        IPAddressRange parsedIp;
        if (!IPAddressRange.TryParse(ip, out parsedIp)) {
            return false;
        }

        return facebookIpRanges.Any(cidr => IPAddressRange.Parse(cidr).Contains(parsedIp));
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea how Facebook crawls websites, but isn't it a bit weird to see error happen over multiple browsers/devices if they are all coming from the Facebook crawlers?

Comment: @RMenke Good catch. Is that not errors coming from iframes loaded by Facebook on Instagram and Facebook?

Comment: @RMenke it is weird, but the data doesn't lie - see my edited answer for my logs of facebook IPs causing the error on mixed platforms/browsers

Comment: You can get an always up to date list of Facebook crawler ips with `whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route  ` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/

Comment: @Jake thanks.  I have updated my answer to include this command and a code example of how to use the CIDR entries.

Answer (score 0):

You might be a victim of the confusion I experienced while using service workers through the [Workbox window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window). That package makes use of two different instances of its modules. There's a set of static modules. There's equally another set residing under the umbrella of the main Workbox module. These ones internally invoke their static counterparts

```
var payload = {key: "value"},

{ Workbox, messageSW } = await import('workbox-window'), // these represent static modules without a contextual `this`

wb = new Workbox('/service-worker.js'); // calls to this works on a single instance that interfaces with the underlying static equivalents
```

This implies that while you'll need to do

```
messageSW(wb.getSW(), payload);
```

Calling `wb.messageSW(wb.getSW(), payload)` results in OP's error, because the actual payload here is the cyclic service worker instead of our object literal payload. The instantiated version, in this case, would work with:

```
wb.messageSW( payload);
```